# NPM : Create an NPM package that adds files and folders to the project root directory

Tags: npm

I've created a web app template that I use frequently for many different projects.

I would like to create an NPM package for it so that it's easier to install for new projects, separate the template from the project files, separate the template dependencies from the project dependencies, and allow easier updating of the template across all projects.

The issue I have is that I need some files/folders to be installed in the root directory (i.e. where `package.json` is saved). Most can go in the `node_modules` folder however I have some files that must be placed in the root directory.

For example, the template uses Next.js with a custom `_app.js` file. This must be in the root directory in a folder named `pages`. I also have various config files that must be in the root directory.

Can this be done with NPM, or does everything need to be installed in the `node_modules` folder? I'm having trouble finding anything on SO or Google that answers this, so if you happen to know a guide online on how to do this or can outline things I should search for it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I feel like NPM is not the right tool for the job here, as it is meant for adding complete and immutable packages to a project, whereas a template is usually designed as base to subsequently modify.

Comment: Npm provides [pre and post hooks](https://medium.com/yld-engineering-blog/using-npm-pre-and-post-hooks-d89dcf2d86cf). Consider adding a `postinstall` script to your _package.json_, e.g. `"scripts": { "postinstall": "..." },`. Add to that script logic to move (or copy) the necessary files from _node_modules_ to the root of your project - [move-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/move-cli) may help with that. The `postinstall` script automatically fires after your npm package has been installed. Essentially, include the file(s) in your project and utilize the `postinstall` script  to move them.

Comment: @RobC Your comment essentially just repeats what I already wrote in my answer yesterday.

Comment: @GoloRoden - Yes you’re correct I missed the _“PS”_ part when reading it previously. I got as far as _”Last but not least..”_ . Anyway, I’ll leave my comment as it provides further context  to what your high level comment means, I.e. _”use the `postinstall` step ...”_ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pure npm, everything *has* to go to the `node_modules` folder, so you can't solve your issue this way.

Maybe going with a templating tool such as [grunt init](https://gruntjs.com/project-scaffolding) or [yeoman](https://yeoman.io/) could be a solution here, although – unfortunately – you'll then lose some of the benefits of being able to install a package via npm.

Another option might be to use [GitHub template repositories](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-template-repository), which have just been introduced recently.

Last but not least one option might also be to just have the files' contents in the npm package, but create the `pages/_app.js` manually, but inside of it simply `require` the file contents from an npm module, and that's it. This at least helps to have the content portable, but of course it still asks you to setup the file and folder structure on your own.

Sorry that I don't have a better answer, but I hope it helps anyway.

PS: One "solution" might also be to use the `postinstall` step in an npm module's `package.json` file to create folder structure, copy files to where they should be and so on, but at least to me this feels more like a clumsy workaround than like a real solution.